# Limit of the sequence $x_{n+1} = λx_n + (1 − λ)x_{n−1}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let ${x_n : n = 0, 1, 2, . . .}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that
$x_{n+1} = λx_n + (1 − λ)x_{n−1}$ for n ≥ 1 and for some $λ, 0 < λ < 1$.
Find the limit of the sequence.
My approach, through iteration we can prove  $x_n = x_0 + (x_1 − x_0)\sum^{
n−1}_{k=0}(λ − 1)^k$

If we take lim it becomes a GP and lim should be $x_0 + \frac{(x_1 − x_0)}{2-λ}$

Please verify?

Comment: sounds good to me

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is fine.

Here is an alternative solution.

We have $x_n = \alpha 1^n + \beta (\lambda-1)^n$, since the roots of $x^2 = \lambda x + (1 − \lambda)$ are $1$ and $\lambda-1$.

Then clearly $x_n \to \alpha$ since $(\lambda-1)^n \to 0$ because $|\lambda-1|<1$.

Solving
$x_0 = \alpha + \beta$,
$x_1 = \alpha + \beta (\lambda-1)$
gives
$$
\alpha = \frac{x_0+x_1-\lambda x_0}{2-\lambda}
$$
which agrees with your answer.